# .innerHTML is showing up as undefined

Tags: javascript, dom

ok so I understand this is a very basic JS logic but I am trying to replace any `document.write()` with `.innerHTML` and I tried it with the code below

```
function writeTimesTable(num) {
  for(let i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) {
    let writeString = i + " * " + num + " = ";
    writeString = writeString + (i * num);
    writeString = writeString + "<br />";
    document.write(writeString);
  }
}


function newTable() {
  for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) {
    let para = document.getElementById("paragraph");
    para.innerHTML = writeTimesTable(i)    

  }
}
```

I have a `div` element with the ID of `paragraph` already. I keep getting `undefined` when I look at the `div#paragraph` and the rest of my code outputs under my `script` tag but not in the `div` element. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can we see the HTML? that may be the issue.

Comment: Two problems: 1) your function doesn't return anything. 2) You still have `document.write` in your function.

Comment: sure , `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Debug</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="paragraph"></div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 1):

Your function `writeTimesTable()` needs to return a value. Your `writeString` string, needs to be concatenated as well, you can do that with `+=` like seen below:

```
function writeTimesTable(num) {
  let writeString = "";
  for(let i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) {
    writeString += i + " * " + num + " = ";
    writeString += writeString + (i * num);
    writeString += writeString + "<br />";
  }
  return writeString
}
```

Using `para.innerHTML = writeTimesTable(i)` probably isn't intended, as it will just display the last loop, so you might also want to use `+=` here as well:

```
para.innerHTML += writeTimesTable(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You normally want to avoid `document.write` because it literally writes out to the document.

I have also taken the liberty of doing the DOM creation off-page during the loop, and just add it to the actual DOM at the end. This means you aren't constantly re-drawing the page while you loop.

This is better than changing your `innerHTML =` to `innerHTML +=`, which you would need to do if you wanted to avoid overwriting each previous iteration of the loop.

```js
function writeTimesTable(num) {
  for(let i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) {
    let writeString = i + " * " + num + " = ";
    writeString = writeString + (i * num);
    writeString = writeString + "<br />";
    return writeString;
  }
}


function newTable() {
  const inner = document.createElement('div');
  for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) {
    const item = document.createElement('div');
    item.innerHTML = writeTimesTable(i);
    inner.appendChild(item);
  }
  let para = document.getElementById("paragraph");
  para.appendChild(inner);
}

newTable();
```

```html
<div id="paragraph"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `newTable()` function with the 10 loops is useless. You're doing 10 times the same stuff over a single DOM element.

Don't use `document.write`...

I'd do it like:

```js
function newTable( num ) {
  var HTML = "";
  for (var i=1; i <= num; i++) {
    HTML += i +" * "+ num +" = "+ (i*num) +"<br>"; 
  }
  return HTML; // Return the concatenated HTML
}

document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = newTable(10);
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">asdasdasd</p>
```

Or in a super uselessly cryptic **ES6 way**:

```js
const newTable = n =>
  Array(n).fill().map((_,i) =>
    `${i+=1} * ${n} = ${i*n}<br>`
  ).join('');

document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = newTable(10);
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">asdasdasd</p>
```